# Ajax request returns HTTP 503 but script works fine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http, apache2

today I stuck in the problem with ajax. I'm doing this request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://hostname/controller/action',
    data: {param1 : 'foo'},
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
console.log(data)
    }
    });
```

Script on server side based on Zend. Server - apache2. Response of script is what I expect, but HTTP code is 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable).
If I open this url as get on browser address bar - it returns what I expect(string), but HTTP response code also 503.

What may causes it?

UPD: action contains `echo "Some string";`
GET or POST - not important.
Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:18
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:hostname
Origin:http://hostname
Referer:http://hostname/controller
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: can you please send the action code? what is happening at action?

Comment: Could you also post the request headers and body being passed in - check in chrome dev tools on the network panel.

Comment: in browser it is GET method and in ajax you are using POST method so response must be different depend how your web service is defined.

Comment: My action contains only echo 'True'; statement.

Comment: also check with     .done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
alert( "complete" );
});

Comment: Provided necessary info.

Comment: Is you website in  "maintenance mode" ?
The 503 response is generated server-side, the problem does not come from the Javascript.

Comment: No, other pages of site opens correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on server-side, Zend was modifyied to always return 503. Thanks all for replies

Answer (score 0):

Use complete instead of success and error.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://hostname/controller/action',
    data: {param1 : 'foo'},
    complete: function(response) {
      if(response['status'] === 200) {
        // success
        var data = response['responseJSON'];
        // ...
      } else {
        // ...
      }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, but is will applicable if we need to handle if server is responding without 200 OK. But my server always returns 503